# .attr_accessible where a model does not respond_to? the attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through some clean-up on a Rails 4 application, and I'm wondering if it is safe to assume that an `attr_accessible` attribute can definitely be considered to be redundant if the ActiveRecord-backed model does not respond to the setting of that attribute?

In code terms, does the result of this snippet definitely list attributes for which there can be no valid reason for them to be `attr_accessible`?:

```
MyModel.accessible_attributes.reject do |attr|
  MyModel.new.respond_to?("#{attr}=".to_sym)
end
```

Thanks.